# Why Gt+1 = v(St+1) in Bellman Equation for MRPs?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-chains, markov

In <Lecture 2: Markov Decision Processes> by David Silver on page 19, it has the following Derived formula:
[image: v(s) equation]

I found [image] is equal to [image] which means Gt+1 = v(St+1) **so Gt = v(St)**.

According to Return Defination:

[image]

and according to Gt = v(St):

v(St) = Gt = [image]

But the defination of Value Function is

[image]

which means
v(s) = [image] = [image]
which is absolutly wrong.

My question are:

1. Why Gt+1 = v(St+1)?
2. Where are my derivation mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First big error is a claim that `E[a + b] = E[a + c]` imples `b=c`, this is not how expectations work. In particular `E[a + b] = E[a] + E[b]`, and `E[a + c] = E[a] + E[c]` thus we have `E[b] = E[c]` (and not `b=c`!) so `G_{t+1}` is not equal to `v(S_{t+1})`, but `E[G_{t+1}] = v(S_{t+1})` (which comes from the definition).

In general **equality of funtion value does not make arguments equal**. Same way `f(x + a) = f(x + b)` does not imply `a=b` for say `f(x) = x^2` as it would also hold for x=0, a=-1, b=1.